# java substring returns empty

Tags: java, tree, substring

I'm trying to get the substring from the given String in tree order, my code is

```
    int val1 = 1;
    String cc = "0011001010000000000000000000000";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        String[] sub1 = cc.split(cc.substring(val1));
        cc = cc.substring(val1);
        System.out.println(sub1[0]);
        int u = val1;
        val1 = u + u;
    }
```

so the output i should be getting is ..

```
0

01

1001

01000000

0000000000000000
```

but the output of my code is

```
0

01

1001

01
```

the code works for other values such as

```
String cc = "0110011101010010100001100101001";
```

I try to get the zero values too but I'm getting it for some reason. Can anybody tell me why its not working?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it looks like you are trying to get each level of a serialized tree containing binary digits.

That is, you want to get the first 2^0 characters, then 2^1, 2^2 etc.

```
int val1 = 1;
String cc = "0011001010000000000000000000000";
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    int beginIndex = Math.pow(2, i);
    int endIndex = Math.pow(2, (i + 1));
    string subs = cc.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    System.out.println(subs);
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get successive substrings that double in size. The problem is your use of `split`, which is completely unnecessary; in your `...000000...` example, the string gets reduced to a small size as you're splitting on something common. In your other case, the only split delimiter to be found is at the very start.

```
String str = "0011001010000000000000000000000";
String substr;
int substrLength = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++, substrLength *= 2) {
    substr = str.substring(0, substrLength);
    str = str.substring(substrLength);
    System.out.println(substr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `sub1` array has length 2 after third step(printing `1001`), and you are printing only firt value(so forth step becaming `01`).
Try like this;

```
        int val1 = 1;
        String cc = "0011001010000000000000000000000";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            String[] sub1 = cc.split(cc.substring(val1));
            cc = cc.substring(val1);
            for (String string : sub1) {
                System.out.print(string);
            }
            System.out.println();
            int u = val1;
            val1 = u + u;
        }
```

And the result is;

```
0
01
1001
01000000
```

And if you want to see all of the string cc, change your for loop like this;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

After this, result is;

```
0
01
1001
01000000
0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your attempt to get allways the double of the previous is a bit to complex, when you realize it with a split. Here is a solution simply working with a while loop and two conditions

```
int val1 = 1, last = 0;
String cc = "00110010100000000000000000000";
while(last < cc.length())
{
    if(val1 > cc.length()) {
        val1 = cc.length();
    }
    String forOutput = cc.substring(last, val1);
    last = val1;
    val1 *= 2;
    val1 += 1;
    System.out.println(forOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a very simple tip on the substring methods, not diving into the particular task:

- substring(start, end) will return a substring including start and excluding end: "abcd".substring(1, 3) will return "bc"
- substring(start) will return the substring from start (including) to the end of the original string(including)